# Multi-algorithm compression library for C

Tags: c, lossless-compression

I want my program to be able to use zlib, lzma, lzo and bzip2 compression algorithms.

Is there any compression library for C which simlifies working with multiple algorithms (like libmcrypt supporting multiple encryption modes and algorithms)?

Expecting something like this:

```
struct compressor c;
universal_compressor_init(&c, "lzma", 7 /* compression level */);
universal_compressor_compress(&c, inputbuf, inputsize, outputbuf, &outputsize);
universal_compressor_save_state(&c, statebuf, &statesize);
```

**Note:** It is not about zip/rar/7z/tar/cpio and other archive formats, it's about compression of raw buffers. Think of compressed networking protocol or about random access to compressed block device (like [cloop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloop)).

Answer (score 3):

[LibArchive](http://libarchive.org/) fulfills your requirements.

From the introduction:

> The libarchive library features:
>
> - Support for a variety of archive and compression formats.
> - Robust automatic format detection, including archive/compression combinations such as tar.gz.
>     ...

EDIT: for handling raw streams (at least until they split libfilter from libarchive), consider using [Boost::iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iostreams/doc/home.html) or [libbu++](https://github.com/eichlan/libbu/blob/master/README.md) (just found on GitHub)

Comment: Is it suitable for many little independent headerless compressed buffers?

Comment: Looks like primary goal of libarchive is working with archives as bundles of files, not as compression embedded in some protocol.

Comment: Can I use libarchive filters (without the rest libarchive) with libarchive's public API?

Comment: Unfortunately, not: that feature is planned for a future release. Updated answer.

Comment: If I understood what you are about to do, you might find squashfs very interesting with respect to block compression.

Comment: I also want snapshotting (means efficient storage of similar versions of some big file)... It should be simple and support large volumes of data efficiently.

Comment: Then you could try to implement snapshotting over squashfs by taking advantage of the "append" mode or aggregating it with aufs &co.. Try playing around with [mksquashfs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/mksquashfs.1.html) and simmetrical companion unsquashfs. Caveat: it is a readonly FS. If you still need to do raw stream compression/decompression programmatically, then I suggest you to use Boost.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29433/discussion-between-vi-and-esseks)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend **7-zip** (http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html).  I haven't found anything to beat it for both compression speed and size.

Comment: I want to compress big file preserving random access inside it. So I want to compress little blocks and store index. Does 7-zip provide an API to do it efficiently?

Comment: Yes, that was one of the needs I had (fast single file extraction from large archives).  You might post on the 7-zip forum for more info: http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797

Comment: Will it really handle 13107200 little files of 4096 bytes each well?

Comment: Good question - I'm sure it would only take a few lines of code to find out.

Comment: 7-zip's primary algorithm (lzma) is in fact listed in question. The purpose of the library in question is to be able to switch algorithms easily.